# Need to replace datetime field in SQL query when it equals 9999-12-31 00:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, case-when

I have a datetime field called ACTUALCLOSEDATE and this field is equal to 9999-12-31 00:00:00 when a corresponding field called STATUSNUM = 0.  When STATUSNUM is changed to 1 (when the record is closed) the value of ACTUALCLOSEDATE is changed to current datetime.

In my query, I want to replace the value of ACTUALCLOSEDATE when it = 9999-12-31 00:00:00 with 'Still Open' when it dosen't I just want the date.

I have tried code below with errors.  Ideas?  I don't IIF is available SQL 2008 r2, is it? and if so can I use it?

```
/* This is what I need but it dosen't work in SQL 2008 R2 */
SELECT
IIF (YEAR(ACTUALCLOSEDATE)=9999, "Still Open", ACTUALCLOSEDATE) AS ActCloseDate,
FROM OPPORTUNITY

/* This dosen't work either */
SELECT
CAST YEAR(ACTUALCLOSEDATE)
    WHEN 9999 THEN 'Still Open'
    ELSE ACTUALCLOSEDATE
    END AS Act_Close,
FROM OPPORTUNITY
```

Comment: Is `CAST YEAR` a typo?  It should be `CASE`, not `CAST`.

Answer (score 4):

Your column must be of a consistent data type; in your instance, you are trying to conditionally show a date or a varchar.

You can do:

```
SELECT 
    CASE YEAR(ACTUALCLOSEDATE)     
    WHEN 9999 THEN 'Still Open'     
    ELSE CAST(ACTUALCLOSEDATE AS nvarchar(25))
    END AS Act_Close
FROM OPPORTUNITY
```

You'll want to possibly use `CONVERT` to format the date in the `ELSE` expression into a preferred format.

Comment: See here for using `CONVERT` to format the date in a variety of formats:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN YEAR(ACTUALCLOSEDATE) = 9999 
      THEN 'Still Open'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, createDate, 120) --Format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)
    END AS Act_Close,
FROM OPPORTUNITY
```

You need to convert the date column into a `varchar` so that it is the same type as 'Still Open'

Answer (score 1):

`IIF` is available starting from SQL Server 2012.

You can use the `CASE` statement in 2008 R2. Note that it's `CASE`, not `CAST`.

Comment: You should probably continue using CASE in SQL Server 2012. IIF saves a couple of characters but it is limited to 2 outcomes (CASE is practically unlimited).

Comment: But who need so many outcomes? It's like saying in C/C++/C# you should avoid if..else and use switch..case for all conditional logic.

Comment: More than two outcomes are needed all the time. You're thinking in boolean. Not all conditional logic is boolean.